# Histogram of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a data frame as follow: 
[image]

and I am trying to plot a histogram from it such that the letters {A,B,C,D} are in the x axis and y axis shows the numbers. I have tried the following:

```
df.plot(kind='hist')
```

for which I get the address instead of the plot, i.e:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x11217d5f8>
```

I was wondering how can I show the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need to transpose the `dataframe` to get index `['A','B','C','D']`as x-axis and then plot. Also use `plt.show()` to display the histogram. The latest version of pandas will display directly the plot with axes object displaying. But, for the older versions need to explicitly write the `plt.show()` code to display.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.T.plot(kind='hist')
plt.show()
```